# To have script-like S for Schwartz space

Tags: amsmath, unicode-math

I want this symbol

[image]

My tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % for \mathscr{S} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\mathscr{S}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

My underlying typesetting engine is XeLaTeX.

**How can you have the script-like symbol for Schwartz space?**

Comment: Works here with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `lualatex`. Do you really need `T4,OT1`? Also, you need to change to math mode `$\mathscr{S}$`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load another font for `\mathscr`, for instance Asana Math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} % you need to reload the default
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{S}\ne\mathscr{S}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get this warning *fontspec warning: "script-not-exist", Font 'Latin Modern Math' does not contain script 'Math'.* I am using OSX. Which font should I use there?

Comment: Try with `\setmathfont[BoldFont={latinmodern-math.otf}]{latinmodern-math.otf}`; you might need also to use `Asana-Math.otf` instead of `Asana Math`

Comment: This works **\setmathfont[BoldFont={latinmodern-math.otf}]{latinmodern-math.otf}; \setmathfont[range=\mathscr,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana-Math.otf}**. Thank you for your excellent answer!